# The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'. (Documentation)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a flutter app to show the nearby ATMs to a user. So I collect it position and comapre it to the ATMs positons whicha are stored in cloud firestore.

This is what I did... When I compiled I get an error at the line which contains the code
List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> documentList = querySnapshot().docs;

How should I solve the problem please??

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gab/pages/functions.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:math' show asin, cos, pi, pow, sin, sqrt;


final geo = Geoflutterfire();
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;



class Principal extends StatefulWidget {
  const Principal({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Principal> createState() => _PrincipalState();
}

class _PrincipalState extends State<Principal> {

  //To obatin positon
  Position? position1;

  getCurrentLocation() async {
    Position position = await determinePosition();
    setState(() {
      position1 = position;
    });
  }

  Future<Position> determinePosition() async {
    LocationPermission permission;
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error("Location permissions are denied");
      }
    }
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    // TODO: implement build
   double _toRadians(double degree) {
     return degree * pi / 180;
   }

   //To calculate the Harvesine distance
   double calculateDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
     const double earthRadius = 6371;
     double dLat = _toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
     double dLon = _toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
     double a = pow(sin(dLat / 2), 2) + cos(_toRadians(lat1)) * cos(_toRadians(lat2)) * pow(sin(dLon / 2), 2);
     double c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a));
     return earthRadius * c;
   }


   getCurrentLocation();
   if (position1 != null) {
     GeoPoint userLocation = GeoPoint(
         position1!.latitude, position1!.longitude);
     double radius = 10;
     Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> querySnapshot() async {
       return await _firestore.collection('atms').where("isFunctioning", isEqualTo: true).where('position.geopoint.latitude',
           isGreaterThan: userLocation.latitude - (radius / 111)).where(
           'position.geopoint.latitude',
           isLessThan: userLocation.latitude + (radius / 111)).get();
     }
     //Calculating the distance to each atm
     List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> documentList = querySnapshot().docs;//This is where I'm getting the error
     List<ATM> atmList = [];
     for (DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> document in documentList) {
       GeoPoint atmLocation = document.get('position.geopoint');
       double distance = calculateDistance(userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude, atmLocation.latitude, atmLocation.longitude);
       if (distance <= radius) {
         ATM atm = ATM(
           name: document.get('name'),
           isFunctioning: document.get('isFunctioning'),
           position: GeoPoint(atmLocation.latitude, atmLocation.longitude),
           distance : distance,
         );
         atmList.add(atm);
       }
     }
     atmList.sort((a, b) => a.distance.compareTo(b.distance));
     return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('ATMs'),
       ),
       body: ListView.builder(
         itemCount: atmList.length,
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
           return ListTile(
             title: Text(atmList[index].name),
             subtitle: Text('${atmList[index].distance.toStringAsFixed(2)} km'),
           );
         },
       ),
     );
   }
   else{
     return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('ATMs'),
       ),
       body: Center(
         child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Color(0xFFee7b64),),
       ),
     );
   }

  }
}
class ATM {
  String name;
  bool isFunctioning;
  GeoPoint position;
  double distance;

  ATM({required this.name, required this.isFunctioning, required this.position, required this.distance});
}
```

Im getting the error at the line which contains
`List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> documentList = querySnapshot().docs;`

Answer (score 1):

Your `querySnapshot` function returns a `Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>`. The `Future` in there means that the `QuerySnapshot` is asynchronously loaded, and you need to handle that asynchronous behavior when you call it. Your code currently doesn't do that.

```
List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> documentList = querySnapshot().docs;
```

The two options are to either use `then` or use `await`.

---

With `then` it'll look like this:

```
querySnapshot().then((List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> documentList) {
  ... all code that accesses documentList has to be in here
});
```

---

With `await` it'll look like this:

```
List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> documentList = (await querySnapshot()).docs;
```

Or a bit more readable:

```
var querySnapshot = await querySnapshot();
List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> documentList = querySnapshot.docs;
```

In both of these latter examples, you'll need to mark the block where you use `await` as `async`.

---

To learn more about all of this, see:

- The codelab on [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)
- The Dart documentation on [Asynchrony support](https://dart.dev/language/async) and [Concurrency in Dart](https://dart.dev/language/concurrency)
- [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)
- [Flutter Display Future value in ListView.builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53449940/flutter-display-future-value-in-listview-builder)

Comment: I tried this but there's another problem please. It is saying ''The await expression can only be used in an async function.'' and it suggests me to add the 'async' modifier to the build function. But when i do that it says that the build function is not correctly implemented

Comment: That is correct. You'll want to either use `then` and `setState` or use a `FutureBuilder` to display the asynchronously loaded value. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it